# Where did the gnuwin32 inetutils package go?

Tags: windows, gnu, telnet, gnuwin32

There are traces of the gnuwin32 inetutils package on the net. But it's not at the site anymore. where is it? Specifically where is the gnu telnet app for win32?

Answer (score 2):

Inetutils has a lot of dependencies that make it hard to compile and run directly on Win32 without any POSIX layer. But you can find some of inetutils tools in other packages or use similar Microsoft Windows command line tools. Here is the list of open-source or free [inetutils tools](http://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/index.html) and where you can find them :

- **hostname**: Show or set system host name. You can find it in [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).
- **logger**: Send messages to system log. Not available.
- **ping**: Packets to network hosts. Not available but you can use [Microsoft Windows ping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737478%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command which is similar.
- **traceroute**: Trace the route to a host. Not available but you can use [Microsoft Windows tracert](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757819%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_tcpip_tro_using_tracert) command which is similar.
- **whois**: Whois user interface. You can use [gnuwin32 Jwhois](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/jwhois.htm) as a replacement.
- **ftp**: FTP client. Not available in gnuwin32, but you can [download it from an old Emacs contrib](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/emacs/windows/contrib/ftp-for-win32.zip)
- **tftp**: TFTP client. Not available in gnuwin32, but you can use [Microsoft Windows tftp](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tftp.mspx) command which is similar.
- **rsh**: Remote shell. Not available in gnuwin32, but you can use [Microsoft Windows rsh](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/bchafy/rsh_vista.html) command or use a [port of netkit rsh for Windows Vista or 7](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/bchafy/rsh_vista.html) that don't have it.
- **rlogin**: Remote login. Not available as a native Win32 command line tool (you can use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) but it will not work under your window, it will create a new window)
- **rcp**: Copy files between machines. Not available in gnuwin32, but you can use [Microsoft Windows rcp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490980.aspx) command which is similar.
- **rexec**: a remote execution program. Not available in gnuwin32, but you can use [Microsoft Windows rexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755410%28WS.10%29.aspx) command which is similar but is [not supported anymore  by Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff945216%28WS.10%29.aspx).
- **talk**: a communication program. Not available.
- **telnet**: User interface to TELNET. Not available in gnuwin32, but you can use [Microsoft Windows telnet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782300%28WS.10%29.aspx) but it will not use standard input and ouput which could be problematic. You could also try [dtelnet](http://dtelnet.sourceforge.net/) but it uses its own window. You could also have a look at [telnet clients listed by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_clients), but they sometime use a cygwin back-end.

The other tools are daemons that you cannot find as windows native executable, but you could find equivalent of these tools :

- **inetd**: Interner super-server
- **syslogd**: system service logging faclity
- **ftpd**: FTP daemon
- **tftpd**: TFTP server
- **rshd**: Remote shell server
- **rlogind**: Remote login server
- **rexecd**: server for rexec
- **talkd**: a server for communication between users
- **telnetd**: Telnet server
- **uucpd**: Unix to Unix Copy

If you can't find what you need here, then you should try to use GNU inetutils through cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not very helpful, but: if you only need to find inetutils that can in some or other form run on Windows, then you can find it in [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). If you are specifically looking for the gnuwin32 port, then you are out of luck I guess.